# Performance impact of Composite Unique Constrain(on a lot of columns)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique-constraint

Say that I have a table which I don't want duplicate rows in it.

To avoid equality check, I plan to create a unique index on **MOST (if not all) of the columns**. And in my application I can madly insert the records regardless the equality. Besides some basic query, I don't have any particular performance requirement for this table.

My question is:

1. Is it a bad practice(to create unique index for this kind of purpose only)?
2. If so, what the impact would be?
3. Alternatives? (I can manually hash it and put it along with the hash code, and create a unique index on this single column. However I don't think it is a smart move either.)

BTW, I'm using MySQL if it is DB Engine related issue, although I'm interested to a general explanation.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not bad practice to do that, actually that's the only way to go. The impact is that it's, of course, slower than just inserting. But if you need unique records, that's the approach. Alternatives, as you already figured out, is to concatenate values and hash them, thus having a unique index on hashed column instead of all the columns.

Comment: I forgot to mention a few things - MySQL is able to store raw output of a hash, so if you use `sha1` for hashing, you can allocate 20 bytes to store binary value instead of "regular" 40 bytes for textual representation of a hash. This means each of your records carries 20 bytes of overhead, which, as you can already see, isn't that much. MySQL wouldn't have to work too much to deal with uniqueness. Personally, I'd create a trigger `BEFORE INSERT` which would concatenate the column values, hash them and insert them. Your code would remain trivial in reality so you can "mad insert" :)

Comment: @Mjh Thanks for the insight! Trigger would be a simple way to go on this matter. However I just removed all the triggers from my project due to the controversy of using it. Sometimes I really hate this world that full of 'tradeoffs'.  :)

Comment: Well, I believe you have your reasons. I'm in a different situation and I don't  steer away from things offered to us by the technology. Anyway, good luck with your project and happy new year :)

Comment: 1- Not bad by itself, I already used it in a similar situation - with a very reputable customer- to prevent duplication in insertion instead of checking if the value is present before each insertion, because catching the duplication exception is less expensive than checking before insertion

2- index takes size in the database (if u are concerned) - slower inserts (specially if bulk inserts)

3-If you don't mind the draw backs, it's the best -From MPOV